# creating a string object with spring.net

Tags: c#, string, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, spring.net

I am currently working with spring.net for dependency injection on a .net project c#. I am configuring my spring via xml configuration files. In this I am creating my objects etc.

I would like to create a constant object, with string value within my xml file. Is this possible and if so, how might I achieve this? I want to proceed and use this value in multiple places, hence I am taking this approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MyString is singleton, because of spring objects are singleton by default

```xml
<object id="MyString" type="System.String" factory-method="Copy">
  <constructor-arg index="0">
    <value>SomeStringValue</value>
  </constructor-arg>
</object>
```

Here is how to reference `MyString`:

```xml
<object id="SomeObj" type="ExampleSpring.SomeObj, ExampleSpring">
  <property name="Str" ref="MyString" />
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend encapsulating this string as a readonly field of a class, then register the class with Spring (or whatever IoC other readers use) as singleton-scoped.

The advantage of this is that you are not forced to try to resolve a string object; you resolve the object containing the string (thus allowing you to have many such string-containing objects).

If you really wanted to, you could define parameter-specific injection values when registering an object, using the constructor-arg tag; that way, when resolving a DatabaseObject, when Spring encounters the constructor parameter named "connectionString", it should provide a particular literal that you specify in the XML. More reading at [Rose India](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/spring3/ioc/springconstructorindexargs.html).

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers give reasonable workarounds for configuring string objects in your container.

If you are looking to re-use a string constant in your configuration files, then you'd be better of using a `VariablePlaceholderConfigurer`. Then you can write your config file like:

```xml
<object id="JohnUsingVariableSource"
        type="XmlConfig.StringInjection.Person, XmlConfig">
  <property name="Name" value="${JohnsFullName}" />
</object>
```

Values for the `${JohnsFullName}` placeholder can be configured from many [variable sources](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-variablesource) such as an `appSettings` section in app.config or a Java style properties file.